# SOQL query to find duplicate phone numbers in workbench

Tags: soql

I was trying to find unique phone numbers in contact but for some reason the Distinct and unique functions giving me error. What could be the error and alternative, i tried using agg function but it throws me an error on workbench.

> SELECT AccountID, Account.Name, COUNT(Phone) FROM Contact
> GROUP BY AccountID HAVING COUNT(Phone) > 1

Comment: SOQL does not support DISTINCT or UNIQUE - those are SQL functions. I recommend you read [the documentation for SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_typos.htm), and perhaps do some [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins/get-started-with-soql-queries).

Comment: You'll probably want to do an [aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) using GROUP BY on the Phone value.

Comment: I did try using that on workbench. But this shows me error SELECT AccountID, Account.Name, COUNT(Phone) FROM Contact 
GROUP BY AccountID HAVING COUNT(Phone) > 1

Comment: `SELECT Phone FROM Contact GROUP BY Phone` should give the list of unique phone numbers.

Comment: Ah, I see you changed the question.

Comment: Yeah I am trying it on workbench.

Comment: For the query to work, it must be aggregated

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which phone numbers are duplicated, you shouldn't *count* `Phone`, you should group by `Phone` and count how many records have that phone numer, so `COUNT(Id)`, then filter them with an HAVING clause (as you already did).
Moreover every non aggregated field should be grouped, otherwise you get the following error:

> MALFORMED_QUERY: Field must be grouped or aggregated: *FieldName*

Since you want to get duplicated phone numbers by their account the SOQL should be:

```sql
SELECT AccountId, Account.Name, Phone, COUNT(Id)
FROM Contact
GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name, Phone
HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.

Comment: @SandeepanMukherjee You're welcome. Please consider to mark helpful answers provided to your questions as accepted, to benefit the whole community. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can read why this is a good practice.